# Microsoft Access datasource in visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

what should i do to select Access database in visual studio ?
Hera i am attaching image for your convenience please help..!
how to solve this problem,It does not gives browse option to select access database

[image]

Comment: Just add your Access connection string to the dialog and test the connection with the `Test Connection` button - http://www.connectionstrings.com/access/

Comment: Yes i did it.but it give following message  when  i click on OK button                                           "Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification 
starting at index O."

Comment: Hallo.Please Reply what should i do